# read a text file and parse using comma separator and store it to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am trying to read a file and save the comma separated values to objects in javascript. i tryed like this.. ?

here i an reading text file to variable out, splitting it and save it objects..
is this is correct way toassin valus to objects

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var patternDetails = [
                                {
                                patternIndex :0,

                                patternLineCount : 0,

                                patternPointCount : 0,

                                firstPtIndx:[
                                            {
                                             i:0
                                             }
                                            ],

                                patternPointName:[
                                                {
                                                 i=0
                                                }
                                                 ],

                                patternPoint: [
                                               {
                                                X:0,
                                                Y:0,
                                                Z:0
                                               }
                                              ],

                                secondPtIndx:[
                                              {
                                               i:0
                                              }
                                            ],

                                }
                            ]

            patternDetails=new Array();// Is this object creation correct ?

            function checkFileAPI() {
                if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /**
             * read text input
             */
            function readText(filePath) {

                var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
                if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                    output = e.target.result;


                                    displayContents(output.split("\n"));
                                    };//end onload()
                    reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
                }//end if html5 filelist support


                        /*else if(ActiveXObject && filePath) { //fallback to IE 6-8 support via ActiveX
                            try {
                                reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                                var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
                                //output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
                                file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
                                displayContents(output);
                            } catch (e) {
                                if (e.number == -2146827859) {
                                    alert('Unable to access local files due to browser security settings. ' +
                                     'To overcome this, go to Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level. ' +
                                     'Find the setting for "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" and change it to "Enable" or "Prompt"');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
                            return false;
                        }*/
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * display content using a basic HTML replacement
             */


         function displayContents(txt)
            {
                var ver =txt[4].split(",");
                var i=0;
                var z=0;
                    patternDetails[i].patternIndex=new patternIndex(ver[++z]);// can i do this . is this is correct wary?

                    patternDetails[i].patternLineCount=new patternLineCount(ver[++z]);
                    patternDetails[i].patternPointCount=new patternPointCount(ver[++z]);

                    for(var b=0;b<patternDetails[i].patternLineCount;b++)
                    {
                        patternDetails[i].firstPtIndx[b]=new firstPtIndx[b](ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPointName[patternDetails[i].firstPtIndx[b]]= new patternPointName(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].firstPtIndx[b]].X= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].firstPtIndx[b]].Y= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].firstPtIndx[b]].Z= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);

                        patternDetails[i].secondPtIndx[b]=new firstPtIndx[b](ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPointName[patternDetails[i].secondPtIndx[b]]= new patternPointName(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].secondPtIndx[b]].X= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].secondPtIndx[b]].Y= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);
                        patternDetails[i].patternPoint[patternDetails[i].secondPtIndx[b]].Z= new patternPoint(ver[++z]);
                    }

                var p= patternDetails[0].patternPoint[patternDetails[0].firstPtIndx[0]].X;
                var q= patternDetails[0].patternPoint[patternDetails[0].firstPtIndx[0]].Y;
                var r= patternDetails[0].patternPoint[patternDetails[0].firstPtIndx[0]].Z;
                DRAW_SP(p,q,r);

                var el = document.getElementById('info');
                el.innerHTML = ver; //display output in DOM


            }
```

the tlr file thet i am readong is

```
//TLR:Format:Vishama Creations:v1.0 
//Pattern_no,Pattern_NumLines,FrstPointIndx,PointName,aX,aY,aZ,bX,bY,bZ,SecondPointIndex,PointName,aX,aY,aZ,bX,bY,bZ 
2
L 
,0,23,24,0,f:p0,0.008,0.235,0.051,1,f:p1,0.008,0.147,0.085,10,f:p10,0.060,0.053,0.109,11,f:p11,0.108,0.050,0.094,12,f:p12,-0.045,0.053,0.111,13,f:p13,-0.091,0.049,0.090,14,f:p14,0.063,-0.049,0.095,15,f:p15,0.081,-0.050,0.082,15,f:p15,0.081,-0.050,0.082,16,f:p16,0.081,-0.050,0.082,17,f:p17,-0.048,-0.049,0.096,18,f:p18,-0.063,-0.050,0.084,18,f:p18,-0.063,-0.050,0.084,19,f:p19,-0.063,-0.050,0.084,1,f:p1,0.008,0.147,0.085,2,f:p2,0.008,0.051,0.102,1,f:p1,0.008,0.147,0.085,4,f:p4,-0.049,0.156,0.108,1,f:p1,0.008,0.147,0.085,7,f:p7,0.065,0.156,0.107,2,f:p2,0.008,0.051,0.102,10,f:p10,0.060,0.053,0.109,2,f:p2,0.008,0.051,0.102,12,f:p12,-0.045,0.053,0.111,2,f:p2,0.008,0.051,0.102,3,f:p3,0.008,-0.049,0.106,3,f:p3,0.008,-0.049,0.106,14,f:p14,0.063,-0.049,0.095,3,f:p3,0.008,-0.049,0.106,17,f:p17,-0.048,-0.049,0.096,4,f:p4,-0.049,0.156,0.108,21,f:p21,-0.055,0.181,0.084,4,f:p4,-0.049,0.156,0.108,5,f:p5,-0.105,0.151,0.095,5,f:p5,-0.105,0.151,0.095,20,f:p20,-0.103,0.165,0.082,5,f:p5,-0.105,0.151,0.095,6,f:p6,-0.118,0.146,0.082,7,f:p7,0.065,0.156,0.107,22,f:p22,0.071,0.179,0.083,7,f:p7,0.065,0.156,0.107,8,f:p8,0.120,0.151,0.094,8,f:p8,0.120,0.151,0.094,23,f:p23,0.119,0.163,0.083,8,f:p8,0.120,0.151,0.094,9,f:p9,0.133,0.147,0.084
```

Comment: 1) be specific. What is not working? 2) create a jsfiddle.net and include examples from the text file

Comment: So what is the exact issues? You have the bits you need

Comment: i neeed to read those values from file and construct line with respect x,y,z,values

Comment: Yes, and what is stopping you?

Comment: adding values to object literals i stopping me..